# Ratio of degrees of nodes in Graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I have a question regarding to graph and ratio of degrees of nodes in graphs.

See the following image:

[image: The GRAPH]

I'm going to find a relation between $A$ and $C$. So, I count all links from $C$ to $B$s $= \{B_1, B_2, B_3, \dotsc\}$, and all links from $A$ to $B$s $= \{B_1, B_2, B_3, \dotsc\}$. Then I calculate the ratio. Based on the ratio, I define how well $A$ and $C$ are related. 
Is there any name for this way? Or any paper to give me more info?

Comment: I don't quite see how the **ratio** would be any good for defining how "*related*" $A$ and $C$ are. For example, if your set of $B$s is $\{B_1, \dotsc, B_n\}$, if $A$ is adjacent to the even indexed $B$s and $C$ is adjacent to the odd indexed $B$s, your ratio is (about) 1 even though $A$ and $C$ have no common neighbor among the $B$s. Do you perhaps mean something else by "*ratio*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume by "ratio" you mean something like $\frac{|N(A) \cap N(C)|}{|N(A)| + |N(C)|}$ where $N(X)$ is the neighbor set of $X$.

This is an example of "collaborative filtering," and it's a technique applied in machine learning. You can read about it [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6825613) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering), for example.

I presume you are describing a situation of the following form: if $A$ and $C$ are customers and $B_1 \ldots B_n$ are stores, and an edge is included each time a customer makes a purchase from a store, we can compute $\frac{|N(A) \cap N(C)|}{|N(A)| + |N(C)|}$ in the resulting bipartite graph to predict similarity between $A$'s and $C$'s preferences.

This question is really more appropriate for CS StackExchange, by the way.